# Viewing available methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In XCode, when I am about to write  method call, pressing Esc shows all the available methods from that class and all it's superclasses. Is there a shortcut to show ONLY the methods defined in that class?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. But you can see the .h file of the class. Press <kbd>command</kbd> and click with mouse in the class name, or double click it and with left button mouse, click in `Jump to Definition`.

This is the same than read the docs files :)